# Adding icons in tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Looking at [Stack Overflows's tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) if you do a search for *"google"* you'll see a lot of tags have a small icon in them

[image: Stack Overflow google tags]

I am wondering if we can do the same as well and if so how we can make it work for us (because most of the tags would be using a favicon from a website like Paypal's or Google Maps)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can't. [Because](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6147/can-we-have-icons-for-tags-the-way-stack-overflow-has):

> These icons or images are [reserved for companies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable/) that have contacted Stack Exchange Inc. and [paid for the privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean) to advertise on such.